# Convert varchar column to date type

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows:

```
Player    Runs    Date
AA        100     01-jan-2010
AB        130     02-jan-2010
AC        150     01-jan-2010
AA        170     03-jan-2010
AB        100     01-feb-2010
AC        90      05-jan-2010
AA        10      10-jan-2010
AA        100     02-feb-2010
AB        100     01-feb-2010
AC        100     04-jan-2010
```

The date is of varchar type. I want to calculate which player scored the most runs in the month of January. I'm facing issues as I'm not able to convert the varchar to date type hence couldn't use any date functions of SQL

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Date/time functions vary greatly between DBMS, so an accurate tag is vital here.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Actually, where I work we use both Postgres and MySQL, hence both tags. Solution in any db would work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @p-salmon in mysql you can format the date using `STR_TO_DATE()` then you can obtain your desired condition by using following query and as suggested by other you should avoid storing date as a string

```
SELECT
    player,
    SUM(run)AS total_runs
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%b-%Y')
BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND LAST_DAY('2010-01-01')
GROUP BY
    player
order by total_runs desc
limit 1;

+---------+------------+
| player  | total_runs |
+---------+------------+
| AA      |        280 |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi Kamal, Can you please explain to me the logic behind using 
"BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND LAST_DAY('2010-01-01')" I'm not able to figure this out.

Comment: Basically `LAST_DAY('2010-01-01')` returns the corresponding value of last day of month(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day), in this case last monthly date of Jan, 2010. Since BETWEEN clause is inclusive on both end of dates i.e. it will include `2010-01-01` and last date of that particular month returned by `LAST_DAY('2010-01-01')`, so it will retrieves all the records for that particular month.

Answer (score 2):

If your only problem is converting date then please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

here's an example

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01-SEP-2020', '%d-%b-%Y');
+----------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('01-SEP-2020', '%d-%b-%Y') |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2020-09-01                             |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Storing dates as strings is a really, really, really bad idea.  There are built-in data types and functions to handles dates and times.  And you are specifically neglecting that database functionality.

However, you don't need to convert the format to a date to do what you want.  Just use string operations:

```
select player, sum(runs) as total_runs
from t
where date like '%-jan-2010'
group by player
order by total_runs desc
limit 1;
```

Of course, you should expend your effort fixing the data, rather than trying to formulate queries.  The specific fix depends a bit on the database, and your question never had an unambiguous database tag.

Comment: Of course, I completely agree with you, there was a specific problem and this is just an example of how my data is.